# Прошивка хотлера

Tags: взлом, прошивка

Всем привет. Такой вопрос. Делал замеры давления через холтер. Он пишет себе их в память, а потом снимаются результаты в больнице. Есть какая нибудь возможность подключится к нему, и поменять результаты на нужные? Есть порт USB в нём

Comment: По лестнице побегайте, когда пишите, что спите. А так, зависит от конкретной модели и выяснять боюсь надо у производителя

Comment: Попробовать скачать ПО на сайте производителя.